# How to calculate values depending on the training type?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have several numbered types of training that have associated values.

Types of possible training:

1. small: 0.5
   big: 0.7
2. small: 0.7
   big: 0.8
3. etc...

If training type number 1 is chosen, how can I determine the pair of associated values for use in calculations? For example, if training type is 1:

```
small = (220 - 60)*0.5
big = (220 - 60)*0.7
```

I want to know how to write code so that the values used in subsequent calculations varies according to the training type selected.

What I have so far:

```
training = str(input("Choose training type (1, 2, 3): "))
s1 = 0.5
s2 = 0.7
s3 = 0.8
b1 = 0.7
b2 = 0.8
b3 = 0.88
spulse = "Small pulse: "
bpulse = "Big pulse: "
if training == 1:
    small = (220 - 60) * s1 
    big = (220 - 60) * b1
elif training == 2:
    small = (220 - 60) * s2
    big = (220 - 60) * b2
elif training == 3:
    small = (220 - 60) * s3
    big = (220 - 60) * b3

print(spulse + str(small) + bpulse + str(big))
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking, can you elaborate more?

Comment: edited post and added code

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 the `input()` function returns a string (unlike in Python 2), but all your `if training == ...` statements are comparing the value it returned to an integer, so they will always fail. To fix that change the first line as shown below:

```
#training = str(input("Choose training type (1, 2, 3): "))  # NOT THIS.
training = int(input("Choose training type (1, 2, 3): "))  # Convert to integer.
s1 = 0.5
s2 = 0.7
s3 = 0.8
b1 = 0.7
b2 = 0.8
b3 = 0.88
spulse = "Small pulse: "
bpulse = " Big pulse: "
if training == 1:
    small = (220 - 60) * s1
    big = (220 - 60) * b1
elif training == 2:
    small = (220 - 60) * s2
    big = (220 - 60) * b2
elif training == 3:
    small = (220 - 60) * s3
    big = (220 - 60) * b3

print(spulse + str(small) + bpulse + str(big))
```

Output produced:

```
Small pulse: 80.0 Big pulse: 112.0
```

**Update**

It would be better to use a Python dictionary to do this. Doing so—which is known as being "data-driven"—will also make it easier to debug and extend, either by adding more training types and/or having more values associated with each one. I think also it makes the code clearer and more readable.

This shows what I mean:

```
# Dictionary associating each training type to associated values.
training_types = {
    "1": {"s": 0.5, "b": 0.7},
    "2": {"s": 0.7, "b": 0.8},
    "3": {"s": 0.8, "b": 0.88}
}

choice = None
while choice not in training_types:
    choice = input("Choose training type (1, 2, or 3): ")

training_type = training_types[choice]
difference = 220 - 60
small = difference * training_type["s"]
big = difference * training_type["b"]

print("Small pulse: {}  Big pulse: {}".format(small, big))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built-in input function you can do as follows:

```
question=input('Choose type 1 or type 2: ')
if question=='1':
        small=(220-60)*0.5
        big=(220-60)*0.7
        type1_total=small+big
print(type1_total)
```

Results:

```
192.0
```

Comment: it must automatically calculate type1 training big and small. Like small pulse 80 and big pulse 120...

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you cast the `input` as an `int` rather than a `str` and if you initialize `small` and `big` outside of the decisional statement like so:

```
training = int(input("Choose training type (1, 2, 3): "))
s1 = 0.5
s2 = 0.7
s3 = 0.8
b1 = 0.7
b2 = 0.8
b3 = 0.88
spulse = "Small pulse: "
bpulse = "Big pulse: "
small = 0
big   = 0
if training == 1:
    small = (220 - 60) * s1 
    big = (220 -60) * b1
elif training == 2:
    small = (220 - 60) * s2
    big = (220 -60) * b2
elif training == 3:
    small = (220 - 60) * s3
    big = (220 -60) * b3
```

However, one alternative approach could be the following:

```
value = 220 - 60
type_ = 0
types = {1 : [0.5, 0.7], 
         2 : [0.7, 0.8],
         3 : [0.8, 0.88]}

while type_ not in types:

    type_ = int(input("Pick a type: "))

    if type_ not in types:

        print("Invalid type.")

    else:

        big   = value * types[type_][0]
        small = value * types[type_][1]

print("Big   = " + str(big))
print("Small = " + str(small))
```

Such that if the user inputs `1` as the value of `type_` at the prompt, the output is:

```
Big   = 80.0
Small = 112.0
```

However, if the user inputs `2` as the value of `type_` at the prompt, the output is:

```
Big   = 112.0
Small = 128.0
```

If the user inputs `3` as the value of `type_` at the prompt, the output is:

```
Big   = 128.0
Small = 140.8
```

And for any other value entered, the output is `print("Invalid type.")`.